# how to return a "close window" command from a GET call?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, rest, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Due to some limitations in the platform I'm using, I need to work with API calls using the GET method for my task.

When the user presses a button, the browser navigates to the relevant URL in a new window. This URL is an API call using the GET method. this API just runs some tasks in the background, so I want to give back a command to close the current window.

I cannot change from a GET method and I cannot prevent the window from opening.

Is there any value I can return that would close the browser window automatically? maybe a simple html page with a script? SOmething like "values changed, going back" and a back command might work too I guess?

the API backend is a python script in AWS Lambda, called by AWS API gateway

Answer (score 1):

You could change your Python lambda script to return HTML and execute the `window.close()` javascript function. Make sure to set the `Content-Type` header to `text/html` in the response. I just tested this on a freshly created AWS lambda function using the Python 3.7 runtime invoked via API gateway and it worked like a charm, on Chrome at least.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    html_body = """
        <html>
            <head>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    window.close();
                </script>            
            </head>
            <body>
                <p>Operation succcessful. You can safely close this window.</p>
            </body>
        </html>

    """

    return {
        'statusCode': '200',
        'body': html_body,
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html'
        }
    }
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, I can map the response body to be the correct one, but the header insists on being application/json; How can I change that?
Under integration response -> header mapping, I put "Content-Type" and "integration.response.header.Content-Type".
On the mapping template, I put text/html and $input.path('body').

Under Method Response I set the header to Content-Type and the body to text/html, model empty.